# Create a paypal donate button with a dynamic notification url?

Tags: paypal

I have been bashing my head against the Paypal developer portal. Its missing information, has out of date information or links just go to 404s. I am trying to do something really simple.

I am trying to create a basic button with a notification url including a custom parameter.
eg: 
www.mydomain.com/paypalipn.html?clientID=1232312321

Every time I create the button in the sandbox portal it creates an uncustomizable HTML button as per so:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="HFYXEE3BN8RM2">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Is there a way to customize the notification url using a Paypal button to add the parameter in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a hosted button, in which you cannot have a dynamic URL. You will need to create a non-hosted/decrypted button in order to use dynamic IPN URL.

Eg:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your_email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.yourdynamicIPNurl/ipn_code.php">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks - where is the documentation for this?

Comment: `notify_url` is mentioned here : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Most of the paypal parameters such as tax, shipping can be over-ridden by using the paramters listed here.

Comment: Thanks - where is the documentation for the form elements that you shared - I want to make sure this is a fully supported implmentation by PP and I can't see it in their docs anywhere

Comment: i already shared the URL, the form elements(parameters) are in that link
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: Thanks do you want to add this as an answer? as it solved it for me. Thanks @Vimalnath

Comment: @MobileBloke sure, you can do that :)